# Ideal number of replicas for database

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, docker-swarm

I am looking for some best practices to be able to read enough to gauge how to decide on the number of replicas needed for Mongo. I am aware of Mongo Docs that talk about things like having odd number of nodes, and when does the need of arbiter arise, etc.

In our case the requirement for reads won’t be so high that reads will become a bottleneck. Neither are we targeting sharding at this moment. However, we are going to run mongo in a docker swarm and there could be multiple instances of certain services trying to write. Our swarm cluster won’t be very huge either most likely.

So how do I find logical answers to these:

1. Why not create one local mongo instance per physical node and tie it to that?
2. For any number of physical nodes, as long as read/write is not a bottle neck, 3 or 5 replicas are always going to be ideal for fault recovery and high availability. But why is 3 or 5 a good number. Why not 7 if I have say 10 physical nodes.

I am trying to find some good reads to be able to decide on how to arrive at a number. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

To give you an answer, all depend on many criterias

1. What is your budget
2. How big is your data
3. what do you want to use your replica sets for
4. etc...

As an Example, In my case
We have 3 Data Centers across the country
One of them is very Small

We found our sweet spot in terms of number od nodes being 5
1 Primary + 1 Secondary in DC1
1 Arbiter in DC2
2 secondaries in DC3

Comment: My data i not super huge. It will fit in one disk with few gigs. Regardless of budget the maximum number of physical nodes in swarm might be 7-9. The physical cluster won't go beyond that. I wanted to get a perspective on by reading articles to see if I can have one replica per node or 3 or 5 or 7 and why